# Command prompt interface not updated in windows 10 anniversary update

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-update

I have windows 10 since first day it's released (I upgraded it from windows 8.1 Pro). After Anniversary update my command line interface not updated and I can't use new features like full screen.

So what I must to do?

[image: My windows 10 version]

[image: My Command Line]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the `Options` tab in the `Properties` dialog box for `cmd.exe`. Make sure `Use legacy console` is not checked.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Use legacy console was checked and when I unchecked it fixed. Please write your answer and give extra information for other users. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may happen if the properties for `cmd.exe` are incorrect. Open `cmd.exe` and click on the icon in the top left corner to get the cmd context menu.

Choose `Properties` at the bottom of the context ment, and on the dialog select the first tab: `Options`:

[image: cmd.exe options]

Make sure the checkbox `Use legacy console` is not checked, and configure the other options to your need.